# PyTest: Mock an object attribute so it changes with each call

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to create a unit test for a while loop that checks if an object's attribute has changed. A pseudocode version of what I'm testing is:

```
def test():
   while a.status != "status2":
      time.sleep(10)
      update(a)
```

where `update` pulls information from a database table to puts it on the object `a`.

I'm trying to create a unit test for this while loop so that it runs through two times before breaking.

```
def test_while_loop(mocker)
   with mocker.patch("src.update") as mock_update:
      mock_update = mocker.MagicMock()
      mock_update.side_effect = [pass, pass, pass]
      
      a.status = mocker.PropertyMock(side_effect = ["status1", "status1", "status2"])

      test()
```

But I keep getting an error that `E   TypeError: '!=' not supported between instances of 'PropertyMock' and 'str'`

How can I set this test up so that the attribute is able to change with each loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Although I would argue using pytest parametrization is probably a better approach than the current one, you can solve your issue by first converting the property mock to a string before checking equality.

Comment: If I covert the property mock to a string by `a.status = str(mocker.PropertyMock(side_effect = ["status1", "status1", "status2"]))` then `print(a.status)` prints "status1" over and over again. It will never print "status2".